# React. How to pass props inside a component defined on a prop?

Tags: reactjs

If we have the following structure on a React application:

```
class BasePage extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <div>
            {this.props.header}
            {/*<Header title={this.props.title} />*/}
        </div>
    }
}

BasePage.defaultProps = {
    header: <header>Base Page</header>
}

class Header extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <header>
            <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
        </header>
    }
}

class TestPage extends BasePage {
}

TestPage.defaultProps = {
    header: <Header />
}

class Root extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <div>
            <TestPage
                title="Test Page Title"
            />
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Root />,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

If we have a *common* component like `<Header />` we can pass a title property easily like `<Header title={this.props.title} />`.

But how can we pass props inside a component if this component is defined as a prop itself?

For example, how can we do something like:

```
{this.props.header title={this.props.title}}
```

So it will render the *Test Page Title* correctly?

Important note: we could overwrite the *render* method inside the Test component. But the purpose of this question is to solve this problem without doing this.

Comment: Well, first of all you can't assign props, they are read-only. Second, `this.props.header` is just JSX, it doesn't take any props.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, [`props` are read-only](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only) and a component should never be update it's own `props`, so lines like

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.header = <header>Base Page</header>
}
```

should not be used.  [`defaultProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops) can do what I think you are trying to do:

```
class BasePage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
            {this.props.header}
            {/*<Header title={this.props.title} />*/}
        </div>
    }
}

BasePage.defaultProps = {
    header: <header>Base Page</header>
}
```

Secondly, [inheritance is not often done in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance).  I'm not saying don't do what your'e doing, but take a [read of the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#specialization) and see if there is perhaps a simpler way to achieve the same goals.

Finally, setting props on components passed as props.  There are a couple different ways to do this.

If you pass the `Component` rather than the `<Component />` you can add props like normal:

```
ChildComponent = (props) => {
  const HeaderComponent = props.header
  return <HeaderComponent title="..." />
}

ParentComponent = () => <ChildComponent header={Header} />
```

You can [clone the element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to override props:

```
ChildComponent = (props) => {
  const HeaderComponent = React.cloneElement(props.header. { title: "..." })
  return <HeaderComponent />
}

ParentComponent = () => <ChildComponent header={<Header />} />
```

**NOTE:** I have used [functional components instead of class components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components) for brevity, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: Thx. In fact I used componentWillMount and I agree this is not the recomended approach (the truth is I was using defaultProps but here I used this bad approach and I will edit). *const HeaderComponent = props.header* is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a great use case for [`React.cloneElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement).

`React.cloneElement(this.props.header, { title: this.props.title });`

It returns a clone of the component with the new props included.